# "supervisor dead but pid file exists" while trying to start hue in dockerfile

Tags: docker, hortonworks-data-platform, hue

I created a dockerfile which includes:

```
#Start Hue
RUN /etc/init.d/hue start
```

For building the dockerfile, I am doing

```
docker build --no-cache --rm=true -t hue-centos .
```

During build, I get the following output

```
Step 13 : RUN /etc/init.d/hue start
 ---> Running in 7d61c0c3a327
 Detecting versions of components...
 HUE_VERSION=2.6.1-3485
 HDP=2.3.4
 Hadoop=2.7.1
 Pig=0.15.0
 Hive-Hcatalog=1.2.1
 Oozie=4.2.0
 Error: No matching Packages to list
 Ambari-server=
 HBase=1.1.2
 Knox=0.6.0
 Storm=0.10.0
 Falcon=0.6.1
 Starting hue: [  OK  ]
```

and then run the docker container using the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 hue-centos:latest bash
```

However, I see the hue supervisor is dead and I have to manually start again in the CLI and it works fine and I can access Hue on the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
RUN /etc/init.d/hue start
```

with

```
CMD ["/etc/init.d/hue", "start"]
```

RUN commands are just used to run build steps as part of configuring the image. CMD tells the image what to do when it starts.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: for some reason, CMD starts it but eventually it is shut down. I get `supervisor is stopped` when I do `/etc/init.d/hue status`. I have to start manually again.

Comment: Oh, it might have to do with way you are running it. Now that you are using CMD, start the container with `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name mycontainer hue-centos:latest` then do a `docker ps` to confirm it is running and `docker logs mycontainer` to see the logs. If you still want to get a shell you can do `docker exec -it mycontainer bash`